# URL to dataset in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Using Colab or Jupyter Notebook with Python. Trying to use a URL to link to dataset needed. When I open labelFile, the CSV file downloads so the URL links work.

```
path = os.system("start \"\" http://decadeofdata.com/datasets/TurnSignDetection/myData") 
labelFile = os.system("start \"\" http://decadeofdata.com/datasets/TurnSignDetection/labels.csv")
```

This error suggests that my method isn't working.

```
for x in range (0,noOfClasses):
myPicList = os.listdir(path+"/"+str(count))
for y in myPicList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(path+"/"+str(count)+"/"+y)
    images.append(curImg)
    classNo.append(count)
print(count, end =" ")
count +=1
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Any suggestions? I couldn't run this as a py file on my local machine.

Link to Colab.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VlZVGPmd6AEMMvZ-98cTmrvYtDgun8HI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is probably here:

```
path = os.system("start \"\" http://decadeofdata.com/datasets/TurnSignDetection/myData")
```

if you do `type(path)` or `print(path)` i think what you will get is the return code of os.system which will be 0 or 1 depending on whether or not the operation succeeded which in turn causes the addition here:

```
 myPicList = os.listdir(path+"/"+str(count))
```

to fail because adding 0 or 1 to `'/'` fails

it's probably best if you turn to [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to do the downloading instead of using `os.system`

Answer (score 0):

```
_URL = "http://decadeofdata.com/datasets/TurnSignDetection/myData.zip"

zip_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=_URL,
                                   fname="myData.zip",
                                   extract=True)

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'myData')

print(path)

_URL = "http://decadeofdata.com/datasets/TurnSignDetection/labels.csv"

label_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=_URL,
                                   fname="labels.csv",)

labelFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(label_file), 'labels.csv')
```

So far this worked and now I am trying to get pickle to work.